# emergency mode help

Tags: ubuntu-mate, recovery-mode

My computer keeps going to emergency mode. I tried boot-repair and checked and repaired file system.

New addition:
If I re-install ubuntu mate, will I lose all my customizations?

```
ACPI Error Namespace lookup failure AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)

ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB>PCIO.VGA.ATCO, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)

ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB>PCIO.VGA.ATCS, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
```

[image]

Comment: you need to give more information what version of ubuntu are you running,is it single boot or dual boot,what have you tried to do to solve this so far?

Comment: @trond hansen I re-installed it again.

Comment: Did the re-install change anything? Can you boot with nomodeset? Have you updated the driver for your video card? What video card do you have?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it now boots all the way up. I lost all my customizations and am still reinstalling a plethora of items. I was surprised that restoring a working Clonezilla image did not even work. I thought it did a sector by sector copy?

Comment: If you did a Clonezilla clone copy, it doesn't work to a smaller destination disk.

Comment: It was not a clone copy but in a compressed form. I have been doing those a long time. @heynnema